# How to solve this ambiguity with Ragel?

Tags: ruby, state-machine, ragel

I am trying to parse the following format: `(identifier/)?identifier(/keyword)?`, with the first identifier as well as the keyword optional.  A keyword may not be used as an identifier.  For example, if `up` is a keyword, then:

- `simple` matches the second identifier,
- `first/second` matches `first` as the first identifier, and `second` as the second one,
- `second/up` matches `second` as a second identifier and `up` as a keyword.

Using [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) with Ruby, I have defined the following FSM:

```
%%{
  machine simple;

  keyword = "up";
  separator = '/';
  ident_char = any - separator;
  identifier = ident_char+ - keyword;

  action start_string { $start_string = p }

  action first_string { puts "First: #{get_string(data, p)}" }
  action second_string { puts "Second: #{get_string(data, p)}" }

  action keyword_string { puts "Keyword: #{get_string(data, p)}" }

  main := ( identifier >start_string %first_string separator )? 
         :> identifier >start_string %second_string 
          ( separator keyword >start_string %keyword_string )?
  ;

}%%

%% write data;

def get_string(data, p)
  data[$start_string...p].pack("c*")
end

def parse(data)
  data = data.unpack("c*")
  eof = pe = data.length

  %% write init;
  %% write exec;
end


parse("first/second")
puts("---")
parse("second/up")
```

This gives the following output:

```
$ ragel -R simple.rl ; ruby simple.rb
Second: first
---
Second: second
Keyword: up
```

which is incorrect, as the first part should be `First: first` `Second: second`, but expected due to the `:>` priority I have given.

I have tried different combination of priorities, but haven't been able to get the expected result.  Is there a way of solving this problem with Ragel (i.e. can this be solved without lookahead)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your main machine:

```
two_idents = identifier >start_first %first_string . separator . (identifier >start_second %second_string);                             

main := (two_idents | identifier >start_first %first_string) . ( separator . keyword )?;
```

The trouble is that the "first identifier" shares a prefix with the "second identifier", so trying to do a guarded concatenation shortcuts the first machine.  The union actually describes the match you're trying to do.